# How do I create a insert method that inserts the objects to a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am currently trying to create and print a linked list that contains the objects ball. The objects are created from file input. I was thinking if I set the head equal to the inseree, I could at least create at least the first object and see where I could go from there. For some reason, the program is displaying 00 which means the object wasn't created and I do not know what I am doing wrong.
Here's the main:

```
class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    // You are not allowed to change the main method.
    
    String inputfilename = "input.txt";    
    String outputfilename= "output.txt";
    BallLinkedList ballSet = new BallLinkedList("", 0, 0);
    constructLLFromFile(inputfilename, ballSet);
    ballSet.printLL();
    
    System.out.println();

    ballSet.printLL();
   }
static BallLinkedList constructLLFromFile(String theInputFile, BallLinkedList ballSet){
    System.out.println("Constructing the linked list from "+theInputFile);
    BallLinkedList head = null;
    try{
      File file = new File(theInputFile);
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
      int data = 0;
      int index = 0;
      while(scan.hasNext()){
        data = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        String color = scan.nextLine();
        long  diamater = Long.parseLong(scan.nextLine());
        int bounce  = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        Ball insertee = newBall(color,diamater,bounce);
        ballSet.insert(insertee,index);
        index++;
      }
    }catch(Exception eee){
        
    }
    
    return null;    // cannot change

  }
}
```

Here is the linked list

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

class BallLinkedList{
  private Planet head;
  
  BallLinkedList(){    
  }
  
  BallLinkedList(Ball initial){
    head=initial;
  }
  
  BallLinkedList(String c, long d, int b){
    head = new Planet(c, d, b);
  }
  //insert method here
  void insert(Ball insertee, int pos){
    if(head == null ){
      head = insertee;

  }else{
    head = head.next;
    pos++;
  }
  }
//print link list
  void printLL(){
   while(head != null ){
    System.out.println(head.getColor());
    System.out.println(head.getDiameter());
    System.out.println(head.getBounce());
    head = head.next;
   }
  }  
  
}
```

Here is the object class

```
class Ball{
  private String color;
  private long diameter;
  private int bounce;
  
  Ball next;
  
  Ball(String c, long d, int b){    
    color = n;
    diameter = d;
    bounce = m;
  }
  
  
  String getColor(){
    return color;
  }
  
  long getDiameter(){
    return diameter;
  }
  
  int getBounce(){
    return bounce;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
    return "Color: "+color+
           "\nDiameter: "+diameter+
           "\nBounce: "+bounce;
  }
}
```

Here's the inout file

```
Blue
48
0
Red
121
0
Green
127
1
Yellow
680
2
Black
120
6
```

Comment: are you trying to create a linkedlist yourself? if so you are missing the "next" attribute for your node

Comment: also your "head" is a Planet object which is probably not what you want

Comment: your scanner loop isn't right either. you are reading multiple nextLine in a single loop

Comment: I recommend you read up on singly linked list